# mongoose stringify removes empty elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am retreiving a **mongoose** object with an empty values from my mongo db :

```
{ _id: 53049728456d4416243bf65f,
  userCreated: {},
  status: { userCreated: {} },
  user: 'patrice',
}
```

which is fine because there is no data.

But when I **stringify** with *JSON.stringify(obj)* this i get :

```
{ _id: 53049728456d4416243bf65f,
  user: 'patrice'
}
```

the keys **userCreated** and **status** haven't been stringified and don't appear in my output...

Any idea where this comes from and how to get arrount it ?

my model is like so :

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  user: type: String, default: '',
  status: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    userCreated: {
      time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }
  },
  userCreated: {
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }
})
```

P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.stringify doesn't normally strip empty objects, so this is mongoose specific.

I'd recommend trying .toObject() or .toJSON()

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

This one will get called during .stringify so it probably is what is cutting out the empty objects.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON

So try this first:

```
JSON.stringify(obj.toObject());
```

Comment: It doesn't help. It seems `obj.toObject()` removes **userCreate** and **status** from the output. same with `obj.toJSON()`

Comment: gotcha! `obj.toObject({minimize:false})` does the trick. it seems minimize is default to true and removes empty objects. Thanks @will-shaver

Answer (score 4):

Try setting minimize to false in the schema options. Worked for me.

```
opts.minimize = false; //stop empty objects being turfed
var s = new Schema(f_obj, opts);
```