# Using JSON.stringify on Javascript object inserts backslashes

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose

I want to create an object like this and then convert it into JSON that can be stored in my mongodb

```
var value1="1"
var value2="2"

var obj = {field1:value1,field2:value2}
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Unfortunately this produces:

```
{\field1\:\1\,\field2\:\2\}
```

FYI, I am using Mongoose and I am attempting to do a push(obj). Console.log shows that the backslashes are added as soon as I stringify the obj.

My actual code is this:

```
var newPaymentMethod = {
            token:token, type: result.cardType, number: result.last4, expiration: result.expirationDate};
```

It looks like it is successfully doing what I want, but the side effect is the backslashes. This is the field as seen in my database:

```
\"token\":\"cpkp86\",\"type\":\"MasterCard\",\"number\":\"4444\",\"expiration\":\"01/2018\"}"
```

That is what I want, minus the backslashes.

Comment: Are you sure?  I get a string without slashes: https://jsfiddle.net/qpzLj5zd/

Comment: I modified the OP to show my actual obj

Comment: It looks like it is replacing `"` with \. Try `console.log('"')` and see if the same result happens

Comment: yes it is. what is the cause and how can i fix it? Modified the OP to show you exactly what it looks like in my databse.

Comment: What tool/app are you using to execute the .js?

Comment: Its an azure server running a node js backend and an instance of express. Can you direct me to the roof?

Answer (score 0):

This is mongoose related issue, try this first: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486577/4029967) (read the comments). Or if you don't want to read:

```
JSON.stringify(obj.toObject({minimize:false}));
```

What I wanted to point out in your code is one thing though:

Instead of:

```
var value1="1"
var value2="2"
```

do this:

```
var value1 = 1,
    value2 = 2;
```

When you put numbers between the quotes they are treated as strings and this can give you a lot of trouble. `value1 + value2` in the first scenario will give you 12 (`"foo" + "bar" = foobar`), meanwhile expected output is 3, which you obtain defining variables as numbers (second case).

Comment: This did not work. That example is for someone who wants to convert a DOCUMENT TO AN OBJECT. Also, js object does not have a method toObject().

Comment: Yep, my fault, sorry for that. Still though keep in mind the consequences of defining numbers as strings. As for your problem this is really weird. When you open console and inspect console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) what does the obj say? Also what is your output for console.log(obj) without stringifying?

Comment: When I stringify the object it gets the backslashes immediately. When i then JSON.parse the new string, I get this : `{ token: '99659w',\n  type: 'MasterCard',\n  number: '4444',\n  expiration: '04/2018' }"}`

Comment: This isn't proper output. Check what's inside and find obj. Look what values it passes. Man you edit faster than speed of light.

Comment: Does anyone know how to remove backslashes from a string? The examples from google do not work on my object after I do JSON.stringify on it.

Comment: I edit because stack overflow comments are stupid. One can not use RETURN for a line break on SO comments, which is the most non-intuitive joke on the web. Hence the editing.

Comment: You can strip the backslashes but that's not a solution tbh. What's the output when you retrieve saved field? Also if I can suggest something: `var newPaymentMethod = {"token" : token, "type" : result.cardType, "number" : result.last4, "expiration" : result.expirationDate};` will do the same but is more reading friendly and you can easily distinguish between defined variables and elements.

Comment: how is it not a solution tbh. i think it would be a fine solution.

Comment: Open your console, copy paste the following as it is: `var x = '{\"token\":\"cpkp86\",\"type\":\"MasterCard\",\"number\":\"4444\",\"expiration\":\"01/2018\"}"';console.log(x)` and hit enter. Then copy the result and paste it here.

Comment: What do you mean by my console. Into node js?

Comment: I mean console in your browser's developer tools/firebug whatever you use.

Comment: It returns the desired Json format without the backslashes. I put it into the node javascript interpreter. Then, when I JSON.stringify(x), it inserts blackslashes. But this time, the backslashes are double

Comment: So even though you put in the escaped values console.log() on retrieving them prints output without backslashes, is that right? I think there is no problem and it is only visual. Nevertheless you might try replacing as you wanted earlier: `JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\\/g, '')` but it shouldn't matter to be honest. Keep in mind saving unescaped signs to the db may compromise your security.